# Firebase: curl with Git bash with unicode

Tags: curl, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, git-bash

I try to run the following line with curl on Git Bash:

```
curl -X POST -d '{ "id" : "fitges2", "text": "Vor für zu sein"}' 'https://myfirebase.com/bmzi-questions.json';
```

As you can see I am using German Characters, but they are not imported in Firebase correctly. I tried to set the settings of Git bash to Unicode:
1. Going on Options->Text-> Locale on de-DE and Character set on UTF-8
2. Running Command: `$ LANG='C.UTF-8'`
But it doesn't work and I get not the write characters for 'ü' in the firebase database. What should I do?